# Reset iDrac Chassis Credentials from node

Tags: ipmi, drac, credentials, password-reset, reset

I have a blade server with 2 nodes.

I cannot access the chassis drac web interface, since I received it configured with a username and password already configured, and the credentials I were given do not work.

I have 2 nodes running and I can access the iDrac web interface of those 2 nodes. For the chassis, I can get to the web interface but the credentials are invalid.

Is there a way I can reset the chassis iDrac credentials from within the node? The nodes are windows 2016 servers and I can access them with no problem, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to reset the chassis credentials.

The server is a Dell PowerEdge FX2s, and the nodes are PowerEdge FC630.

The web interface for the nodes says "Integrated Dell Remote Access Controller 8", not sure if this influences the operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(iwork4dell) Sounds like what you need to do is reset the credentials on the CMC.  Resetting the CMC password on FX2 requires physical access.  The procedure is here:

Dell Chassis Management Controller Version 1.3 for PowerEdge FX2/FX2s User's Guide > Troubleshooting and recovery > Resetting Forgotten Administrator Password

https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/poweredge-fx2/cmcfx2fx2s13ug-v1/resetting-forgotten-administrator-password?guid=guid-89a87153-ad73-4b64-a6d9-82f74506a485&lang=en-us

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping for an easier way, but ended up with a physical maintenance procedure.